# How to separate conditions for different event types in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

We have a workflow file:

```yaml
---
name: 'Deploy Test Env'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - develop
    paths:
      - '**.js'

jobs:
  deploy:
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    name: '[DEV] DEPLOY'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          echo 'Deploy Dev Env by ${{ github.event.action }} event type' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
```

When new Pull Request (`feature_branch` → `develop`) is created or new commit inside `feature_branch` is occured, `pull_request`'s `opened` (or `synchronize`) event is triggering Job.

Here is a `paths` condition: if none of `JavaScript` files are changed, application source code is the same and we don't need to deploy new test environment. That is correct.

But, here is third action type: `edited`. It is used because we have environment parameters passed inside Pull Request message. And if message is changed (`edited`), it means that parameters possibly changed too, and we have to re-deploy test environment even if `**.js` files are not changed. But because of `paths` condition `edited` event will not be triggered too.

In other words, description should be looks like:

```yaml
---
name: 'Deploy Test Env'

on:
  # will be triggered only if *.js files changed
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - develop
    paths:
      - '**.js'

  # will be triggered anytime when PR contents are updated
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
    branches:
      - develop
```

But `YAML` doesn't support duplicated keys and this format is wrong.

OR:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      # paths are set only for `opened` and `synchronize` types
      - type: edited
      - type: opened
        paths:
          - '**.js'
      - type: synchronize
        paths:
          - '**.js'
    branches:
      - develop
```

But `types` should be a list...

**The question is:** Is it possible to describe desired behavior? Maybe `pull_request` may be passed twice as array or `paths` may be set under the `edited` type (something like my second example)

Comment: Have you considered using [`if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution) with [GitHub Actions contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) to handle this?

Comment: @Azeem Currently I'm using `if` condition without `paths` and developers should manually add `[skip build]` tag into commit message to skip deploy task. This shortens workflow run time but looking not so smart and job is still running and can be found inside `Actions` tab. In other way `paths` condition allows to ignore `event` at all and that is more desired behavior

Comment: @Azeem And is it possible to check `paths` easily with `if` condition? Like: `if: ${{ github.event.action != 'edited' || contains(github.something.paths, '**.js') }}`? If my understanding is correct it is not possible to check `paths` without implementing manual logic and scripts

Comment: Looks like you can by using `github.event_name` and `github.event_path`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows for more details.

Comment: @Azeem `github.event_name` is the `pull_request` (and this is only event name in my case). Probably you mean `github.event.action`. What will be `edited` or `opened`, etc. `github.event_path` is a path to `JSON` file with same contents as `github.event` context. Of course it is possible to get changed files by using GitHub API calls to PR URL, but this logic will be more or less complicated and fragile. I'm trying to avoid it

Comment: I don't see `github.event.action` under [contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). Could you please share the link to it? Or, is it not documented and it's part of the `event` object?

Comment: @Azeem You may check this [example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-contexts). Actually, the fastest way to search about `github` context keys/values is to run `echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"` inside workflow ;)

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you very much! I guess you can make use of `github.event.action` as you mentioned above. Alternatively, how about dividing these into two workflows, the YAML won't have those conflicts then and it would be somewhat manageable to filter events. Though, I'm not aware of the rest of the workflow. You better know whether it would be feasible or not.

Comment: @Azeem Actual workflow file has about 200 lines of code and I very very want to avoid of supporting two 99%-identical files. It will be smart to create shared job-workflow and two separated event-triggered workflows that will call shared workflow with specific parameters. But I still dont't undestand how to re-use worflows. I tried to check how to do it, but it looks more complicated than I expected. If you have any working examples of re-using will be glad to see it :)

Comment: Yes, that totally makes sense. IIRC, I have not done anything like this. But, if you could share a minimal reproducible working repo, I'd try to find a working solution by iterating on that.

Comment: @Azeem `But, if you could share a minimal reproducible working repo` → No problem, I added job example inside yaml file.  `[DEV] DEPLOY` job should be common and single. `on:` part may be duplicated depends on action type. Both `on:`s should call same `[DEV] DEPLOY` job. Just create new repo with `feature_branch` and `develop` branches and copy/paste the yaml workflow as is. It will work

Comment: Sure, thanks! I'll experiment with this config and update you later.

Comment: Hi! I did some R&D to find the solution to your problem given all the requirements and constraints but could not find one. Looks like most of the possible solutions and alternatives have already been discussed. The only thing that I could find was this doc on [reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows). You may split the higher-level filter config into two workflows and have another one for the actual work and call that there.

Comment: @Azeem welcome back :) Yes I know that workflows may be reused but as I said before `But I still dont't undestand how to re-use worflows.`. Your link is a really good point to start learn how it works, but as I said before `it looks more complicated than I expected`. And nothing is changed currently. But some day I will see this link. It looks helpful but takes time to check and understand how it works :)

Comment: Same here. :D Otherwise, I would have posted an example. Maybe, in the future, if I encounter something like this, I'll make sure to post it here as well unless you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: This looks like a pretty simple and self-contained example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141318/github-actions-parameter-passing-problem). You might want to look at it for reference.

Comment: Hello again! I just completed testing your complete scenario with reusable workflows. Here's the working example: **repo** (https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test), **PR** (https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test/pull/1), and **actions** (https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test/actions) :) It's working as expected. Let me know if you find any discrepancies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) to achieve this.

Divide your workflow into three (3) workflows:

- `ci.yml`: **reusable workflow** (workflow that performs stuff)
- `ci-pr-opened-synchronize.yml`: **reusable workflow caller** (for PR opened/synchronize for `.js` files)
- `ci-pr-edited.yml`: **reusable workflow caller** (for PR edited)

The above reusable workflow callers will call the `ci.yml` workflow.

---

Here's a complete working example with `.md` files filter and PRs to the `main` branch (https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test):

`ci.yml`

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      message:
        type: string
        description: custom message
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print message
        if: ${{ inputs.message }}
        env:
          MESSAGE: ${{ inputs.message }}
        run: |
          echo "message: $MESSAGE"
```

`ci-pr-opened-synchronize.yml`

```yaml
name: PR opened/synchronize

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - '**.md'

jobs:
  pr-open-sync:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci.yml
    with:
      message: 'PR opened/synchronized'
```

`ci-pr-edited.yml`

```yaml
name: PR edited

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  pr-edited:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci.yml
    with:
      message: 'PR edited'
```

You may check this PR and its respective actions for this sample:

- PR: https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test/pull/1
- Actions: https://github.com/iamazeem/github-actions-reusable-workflow-test/actions

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example of reusable workflows:

- `.github/workflows/reuser_on_edited.yml`
  the workflow will reuse `to_reuse.yml` jobs when PR contents are `edited`

```yaml
---
name: 'Reuser on Edited'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
    branches:
      - 'develop'

jobs:
  reuse:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/to_reuse.yml
    with:
      original_github: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
      other_input: 'BOOM! edited'
```

- `.github/workflows/reuser_on_pr_changed.yml`
  the workflow will reuse `to_reuse.yml` jobs when some of `**.js` files is changed.

```yaml
---
name: 'Reuser on PR changed'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - 'develop'
    paths:
      - '**.js'

jobs:
  reuse:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/to_reuse.yml
    with:
      original_github: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
```

- `.github/workflows/to_reuse.yml`
  the file to reuse jobs inside it

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      original_github:
        type: string
        required: true
        description: "github context that passed from original workflow (JSON)"
      other_input:
        type: string
        default: 'default'
        required: false
        description: "just for LOLs"

jobs:
  deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ fromJSON(inputs.original_github).event.pull_request.head.sha }}

      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          {
            echo 'Deploy Dev Env by `${{ fromJSON(inputs.original_github).event.action }}` event type';
            echo '';
            echo 'Also `${{ inputs.other_input }}` input is passed';
          } >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
```

Original `github` context may be passed as JSON string and reused inside different workflow.

Also, different conditions (`paths`, etc.) may be set for different `pull_request` action types.

Comment: Finally! You got it working. :)