# Cannot retrieve and display Github env setup in previous step

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to setup a variable in my CI pipeline that I will reuse later (eventually in another job, which I don't know if possible since I don't know if jobs shares variables.. but this is another problem). My pipeline is:

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: test-job
    steps:
      - name: setup env variable
        run: |
          BRANCH_NAME=`echo "${{github.head_ref}}"'`
          echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}
```

that last `echo` doesn't show anything unfortunately. I am sure that BRANCH_NAME is correctly set because before pushing it into the `$GITHUB_ENV"` I did `echo` it and it contains data. Plus you can see the name of the branch in the console logs.
Console logs from Github are the following:

```
1. Run BRANCH_NAME=`echo "test_branch"'`
2. BRANCH_NAME=test_branch >> /home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/set_env_9eeeac39-f573-4079-ba62-e1c2019f7aff
3.
```

So, that final `echo ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}` gives no result. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:

As suggested in the comments, I started using workflow variables, in such a way that they are available throughout all the jobs.
The initial setup becomes:

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ""
jobs:
...
```

I don't like the fact I need to give those variables an empty string value as placeholder and would have preferred declaring and assigning them in one of the jobs itself.. but still. So, now variables are declared before the jobs section, how do I assign a value to them in one of my steps? Meaning, I need to replace the

```
echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

tried already

```
echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME >> ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}
```

or

```
${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}=$BRANCH_NAME
```

but both ways don't work.

Comment: `${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}` looks like jenkins pipeline syntax.

Comment: Delcare an `env` section above `jobs` and use that if need those across jobs. `BRANCH_NAME` set to `GITHUB_ENV` will be available in the next step under the same job.

Comment: For reusing workflows, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105072/how-to-separate-conditions-for-different-event-types-in-github-actions.

Comment: See [Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) for more details.

Comment: Also, `echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME >> $GITHUB_ENV"` should be `echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV`. The quote should be fixed.

Comment: I tried fixing the quotes but still doesn't solve the problem. However, declaring an extra section above jobs helps. I don't like the fact I need to give those variables an empty string value as placeholder and would have preferred declaring and assigning them in one of the jobs itself.. but still.
So now variables are declared before the jobs section, how do I assign a value to them in one of my steps? Meaning, I need to replace the `echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME >> $GITHUB_ENV"`

Comment: @Tarta: Please edit and update your question with this change under **UPDATE**. There could be other ways too but you need to add a minimal, reproducible config for this.

Comment: @Tarta: Thanks! Isn't this `echo "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV` working and you're able to see it in the next step with `${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}`?

Comment: nope.. already tried it unfortunately :/

Comment: @Tarta: How do you access it? Could you please a complete working example that I can run to reproduce your issue? Just a small ones with the required config would do.

Comment: @Azeem but the complete working example is the one in the post right? The part before the `jobs` is the new one suggested by you and that I wrote in the UPDATE.
The part after the `jobs` remains identical to the one of the original post. So I am trying to access it via `echo ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}`

Comment: actually from what I read in the docs it makes sense because `env` context is very specific to where it's defined. If I try to export that variable at the step level, only the step level will have access to it. Once I change job, it will go back using the placeholder defined at workflow level, hence at the top.

Comment: @Tarta: Yes, that's like global variables. But, why are you not seeing the change? In your first example, you are setting and using the env var in the same step. But, the env var is available in the subsequent steps i.e. my second comment. If it's the same config then you might need to set env var in one step and then use it in the next one.

Comment: Okey got it clear! So, as you are saying, the variable is not ready yet if called in the same step, but from the subsequent step onwards is available. I don't understand what you meant by referring to your second comment, as it points to a question/thread on how to `separate conditions for different event types in GitHub Actions`. This was not what I was trying to do, right? or did I miss something you were pointing me to?

Comment: @Tarta: Yes, you got that right. About that comment, that was in response to your mention of "reusable workflow". Thought, that might be helpful but if you don't need a reusable workflow ATM, you can ignore it.

Comment: @Azeem, understood! In the meantime I found the solution and it needs the usage of jobs outputs! Will post an answer later in this post to share it:)